# Merge 3 dataframes with different timesteps (10min and 15min and 30min) using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge

The goal is to merge three different dataframes having different timesteps (10min, 15min and 30min. The code must recognize what timestep to consider firstly and identify the next available next timestep. in This example 2019/04/02 10:40:00 does not exist in the dataframes dataset. Therefore the next timestep to consider after 2019/04/02 10:30:00 would be 2019/04/02 10:45:00.

df1:

| Timestamp | data1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2019/04/02 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 2019/04/02 10:10:00 | 1 |
| 2019/04/02 10:20:00 | 1 |
| 2019/04/02 10:30:00 | 1 |

df2:

| Timestamp | data2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2019/04/02 10:00:00 | 2 |
| 2019/04/02 10:15:00 | 22 |
| 2019/04/02 10:30:00 | 222 |
| 2019/04/02 10:45:00 | 2222 |
| 2019/04/02 11:00:00 | 22222 |

df3:

| Timestamp | data3 |
| --- | --- |
| 2019/04/02 10:00:00 | 3 |
| 2019/04/02 10:30:00 | 33 |
| 2019/04/02 11:00:00 | 333 |
| 2019/04/02 11:30:00 | 3333 |

desired result:

| Timestamp | data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019/04/02 10:00:00 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2019/04/02 10:10:00 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2019/04/02 10:15:00 | NaN | 22 | NaN |
| 2019/04/02 10:20:00 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2019/04/02 10:30:00 | 1 | 222 | 33 |
| 2019/04/02 10:45:00 | NaN | 2222 | NaN |
| 2019/04/02 11:00:00 | NaN | 22222 | 333 |
| 2019/04/02 11:30:00 | NaN | NaN | 3333 |

I used the python concat function and the merge function but did not deliver he desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Convert Timestamp columns to datetime
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
df2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp'])
df3['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Timestamp'])

# Sort the DataFrames based on Timestamp
df1 = df1.sort_values('Timestamp')
df2 = df2.sort_values('Timestamp')
df3 = df3.sort_values('Timestamp')

# Merge using merge_asof
result = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Timestamp', direction='nearest')
result = pd.merge_asof(result, df3, on='Timestamp', direction='nearest')
```

EDIT: IF YOU WANT TO KEEP NAN VALUES

```
# Convert Timestamp columns to datetime
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
df2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp'])
df3['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Timestamp'])

# Merge using merge with how='outer'
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Timestamp', how='outer')
result = pd.merge(result, df3, on='Timestamp', how='outer')

# Sort the result based on Timestamp
result = result.sort_values('Timestamp')
```

Comment: Hi Cem, thank you so much for your help. I tried and I got an error "left keys must be sorted". The error appeared in the first line code result = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Timestamp', direction='nearest')

Comment: @JASS I fixed it with a simple addition and tried it myself on dummy data, can you check the current version? Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Cem, thank you again, it worked however the NaN values are replaced with nearest value- the NaN must be kept. applying this to the example above the NaN value in time step 2019/04/02 10:10:00 are filled with 2 and 3 from 2019/04/02 10:00:00

Comment: Ok, I added another version where you can keep the NAN values

Comment: Hi Cem, awsome! thank I tested and it seemed to work weel- I very appreciate your help. I was just wondering about the merge_asof hat the option to hinder replacing the NaN values and when could be useful exactly.

Comment: @JASS No problem, I am happy to help feel free to reach me if you have any more issues with your project

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Another possible solution, which [`concatenates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the 3 dataframes vertically, sets the `timestamps` column as index, [`stacks`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstacks`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) the level corresponding to `data1`, `data2` and `data3`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).set_index('Timestamp').stack().unstack(1).reset_index()
```

---

### Intermediate steps

#### Step 1

The code

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).set_index('Timestamp')
```

produces:

```
                     data1    data2   data3
Timestamp                                  
2019/04/02 10:00:00    1.0      NaN     NaN
2019/04/02 10:10:00    1.0      NaN     NaN
2019/04/02 10:20:00    1.0      NaN     NaN
2019/04/02 10:30:00    1.0      NaN     NaN
2019/04/02 10:00:00    NaN      2.0     NaN
2019/04/02 10:15:00    NaN     22.0     NaN
2019/04/02 10:30:00    NaN    222.0     NaN
2019/04/02 10:45:00    NaN   2222.0     NaN
2019/04/02 11:00:00    NaN  22222.0     NaN
2019/04/02 10:00:00    NaN      NaN     3.0
2019/04/02 10:30:00    NaN      NaN    33.0
2019/04/02 11:00:00    NaN      NaN   333.0
2019/04/02 11:30:00    NaN      NaN  3333.0
```

#### Step 2

The code

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).set_index('Timestamp').stack()
```

produces:

```
Timestamp                 
2019/04/02 10:00:00  data1        1.0
2019/04/02 10:10:00  data1        1.0
2019/04/02 10:20:00  data1        1.0
2019/04/02 10:30:00  data1        1.0
2019/04/02 10:00:00  data2        2.0
2019/04/02 10:15:00  data2       22.0
2019/04/02 10:30:00  data2      222.0
2019/04/02 10:45:00  data2     2222.0
2019/04/02 11:00:00  data2    22222.0
2019/04/02 10:00:00  data3        3.0
2019/04/02 10:30:00  data3       33.0
2019/04/02 11:00:00  data3      333.0
2019/04/02 11:30:00  data3     3333.0
dtype: float64
```

#### Step 3

Finally, the code

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).set_index('Timestamp').stack().unstack(1)
```

produces (notice that `unstack(1)` takes the level `1` of the multindex -- the level with `data1`, `data2` and `data3` -- to form the 3 columns of the final dataframe):

```
                     data1    data2   data3
Timestamp                                  
2019/04/02 10:00:00    1.0      2.0     3.0
2019/04/02 10:10:00    1.0      NaN     NaN
2019/04/02 10:15:00    NaN     22.0     NaN
2019/04/02 10:20:00    1.0      NaN     NaN
2019/04/02 10:30:00    1.0    222.0    33.0
2019/04/02 10:45:00    NaN   2222.0     NaN
2019/04/02 11:00:00    NaN  22222.0   333.0
2019/04/02 11:30:00    NaN      NaN  3333.0
```

---

### Output

```
             Timestamp  data1    data2   data3
0  2019/04/02 10:00:00    1.0      2.0     3.0
1  2019/04/02 10:10:00    1.0      NaN     NaN
2  2019/04/02 10:15:00    NaN     22.0     NaN
3  2019/04/02 10:20:00    1.0      NaN     NaN
4  2019/04/02 10:30:00    1.0    222.0    33.0
5  2019/04/02 10:45:00    NaN   2222.0     NaN
6  2019/04/02 11:00:00    NaN  22222.0   333.0
7  2019/04/02 11:30:00    NaN      NaN  3333.0
```

Comment: Hey PaulS, thank you for your contribution, can you please explain the idea behind the .stack().unstack(1)?

Comment: I have added the intermediate steps to my solution, @JASS. Please, see it, and, in case something is unclear, just point it out to me and I will be glad to further clarify it.

Comment: Hi PaulS, very clear I appreciate your contribution

Answer (score 0):

With an *outer* [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) :

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

merge = lambda *lr: pd.merge(*lr, how="outer")

out = (reduce(merge, dfs).convert_dtypes()
           .sort_values(by="Timestamp", key=pd.to_datetime))
```

Output :

```
             Timestamp  data1  data2  data3
0  2019/04/02 10:00:00      1      2      3
1  2019/04/02 10:10:00      1   <NA>   <NA>
4  2019/04/02 10:15:00   <NA>     22   <NA>
2  2019/04/02 10:20:00      1   <NA>   <NA>
3  2019/04/02 10:30:00      1    222     33
5  2019/04/02 10:45:00   <NA>   2222   <NA>
6  2019/04/02 11:00:00   <NA>  22222    333
7  2019/04/02 11:30:00   <NA>   <NA>   3333

[8 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: hello Timeless, thank you for your help. I tested your solution and it worked as well. 
Can you please explain more the idea behind the reduce function and the key=pd.to_datetime?